# Swift - pushing ViewController not working after presenting ViewController again

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

The question sounds a bit confusing but I don't know how to describe it better.. Let me explain:

The first `ViewController` that gets presented is `FirstLaunchVC`, where he user types in his email and if he is registered he get's to `LoginVC` and from there he get's to `MainVC`. Everything is working fine.

In `MainVC` the user can sign out and get's back to `FirstLaunchVC`. However, after doing the `weiterButton` which should bring the user to `LoginVC` is not doing anything.

**FirstLaunchVC:**

```
@objc func weiterButtonTapped() {

    email = emailTextfield.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    //prüfen, ob Email schon registriert ist
    Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: email) { (methods, error) in

        //Email ist noch nicht registriert -> sign up
        if methods == nil {

            let SignUpView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpVC") as! SignUpViewController

            SignUpView.email = self.email

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SignUpView, animated: false)

        }
        //Email ist registriert -> login
        else {
            print("hi")

            self.view.endEditing(true)

            let LoginView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginViewController

            LoginView.email = self.email

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(LoginView, animated: true)
        }
    } 
}
```

**Main Problem:**

*The `print(hi)` is printing but `pushViewController` is not working after signing out.*

**LoginVC:**

```
func transitionToHome () {

    let homeVC =
    storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? MainViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC!)

    view.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

**MainVC:**

*This is where the user can sign out.*

```
@objc func signoutButtonTapped() {
    UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: false)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    let firstLaunchVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstLaunchVC")

    self.navigationController?.present(firstLaunchVC, animated: true)
}
```

I tried to explain the problem the best I can. If anything is still unclear just let me know. I am happy for any help :)

Comment: a navigation controller is used to push a viewController not to present a new one so change the line to 'self.navigaitonController?.push(firstLaunchVC,animated)'

Comment: ok, that's actually working but I would like to have the `present` animation and not the `push` animation. Is that possible?

Comment: you may change the presentation style google for ti

Comment: yep, found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970617/push-up-view-controller-from-bottom-using-swift . Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

if after sign out weiterButtonTapped() called,

you should put your pushController line in dispatch that's because controller be fully deallocated:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(LoginView, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: this code is running in the main thread is no necessary to check for it, and also why the delay of 3 second when it could be done ASAP. when the button is touched.

Comment: @kjoe navigationcontroller can present controller,
 it's not 3 second it's 0.3 second

Comment: I don’t see a present method in UINavigationControlleronly a show a push remember in uistotyboard a navigation controller can not modalu present a view controller and using 0.3 is not a real difference better use DispatchQueue.main.async{}